# Loop no Python com sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

tenho o seguinte codigo

```
for contrato in df_raw['Contrato']:
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"""
    
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
    
    (
        
         SELECT 
            C.CODIGO_GRUPO
           ,C.CODIGO_COTA
           ,C.NUMERO_CONTRATO
           ,FORMAT(C.DATA_ADESAO,'dd/MM/yyyy') as DATA_ADESAO 
           ,FORMAT(CS.DATA_VENCIMENTO,'dd/MM/yyyy') DATA_VENCIMENTO 
    
            ,CS.VALOR_FUNDO_COMUM
            +CS.VALOR_FUNDO_RESERVA
            +CS.VALOR_TAXA_ADMINISTRACAO AS VALOR_PARCELA
    
            FROM CONSULTA_COTA C
    
            LEFT JOIN COBRANCAS CS
            ON CS.CODIGO_GRUPO = C.CODIGO_GRUPO
            AND CS.CODIGO_COTA = C.CODIGO_COTA 
            AND CS.VERSAO = C.VERSAO
    
    
            WHERE 1=1 
            AND C.NUMERO_CONTRATO = {contrato}
            AND CODIGO_MOVIMENTO = 10
            AND ORIGEM_LANCAMENTO IS NULL
    
    
    
           ) D
           ORDER BY D.DATA_VENCIMENTO ASC
           
                """)


    rs = cursor.fetchall()

    print(rs)
```

a intenção é fazer um loop com cada "contrato" que o meu DataFrame possui, porem ele traz apenas 1 resultado e os outros ele deixa em Lista vazia, segue o resultado do Codigo

```
[(464, 827, 4052295, '03/10/2022', '10/11/2022', Decimal('1012.5000'))]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Se executar o código sql de cada contrato individual, todos eles retornam valores? Para estar retornando vazio quer dizer que ele não deu match com todas as specs do `WHERE`

Comment: Obrigado por me abrir os olhos, estava tão cego no código do Python que esqueci completamente que estou lidando com banco de dados em produção, testei novamente o código com novos dados e funcionou, muito obrigado amigo !!

Answer (score -1):

Apenas uma linha é retornada pq vc ta usando TOP 1 na consulta.

Comment: o Top 1 é apenas para trazer 1 linha de cada contrato,  a sintaxe dessa consulta é trazer a "uma" linha mais antiga de cada contrato, se nao ele iria trazer todas as linhas que constem na base

Comment: Faz sentido retornar somente um único resultado. Ele usou TOP 1, na própria documentação avisa que `SELECT TOP n` é usado para tabelas muito grandes especifica o número de registros exatos que irá retornar. `The SELECT TOP clause is useful on large tables with thousands of records. Returning a large number of records can impact performance.`